# How to sum start time in date format and run time in milliseconds to find end time in unix script?

Tags: unix, timestamp, addition, milliseconds

I have a file having a column with start time in the format shown below.

```
2019-10-30T08:04:30Z
2019-10-30T08:04:25Z
2019-10-30T08:04:30Z
```

Also I have a file having run time of the jobs executed in the format of milliseconds.

```
2647ms 
360ms
10440ms
```

.
.
.

How do I add the respective rows in both columns in those files and produce the end time as a result in seperate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paste start_time.txt execution_time.txt | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r f1 f2
do

  # convert execution_time in seconds from ms
  execution_time_ms="$(echo $f2 | cut -d'm' -f1)"
  execution_time_ms="$(echo $execution_time_ms | cut -d's' -f1)"
  execution_time_s=$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.10f\",$execution_time_ms/1000}")

  # create dateformat string to add seconds 
  date_format=$f1
  date_format+=" +$execution_time_s"
  date_format+="seconds"

  # create end date using dateformat string
  end_time=`date --date="$date_format" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
  end_time="${end_time/ /T}"
  end_time+='Z'

  # append end time
  echo $end_time >> end_time.txt

done
```

This is a script which solves your problem.
I have used 3 files as per you mentioned.

- start_time.txt (Input file)
- execution_time.txt (Input file)
- end_time.txt (Output file)